# Need to trasform a link into another with PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have this youtube link for example: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aICB2mUu2k`

And I need with PHP to transform it in this way: `http://www.youtube.com/e/3aICB2mUu2k`

I need to replace `wathc?v=` with `/e/`

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aICB2mUu2k";
$newString=str_replace('/watch?v=','/e/',$string);
```

[str_replace Manual](http://php.net/str_replace)

**Added after your comment:**
Use [strtok](http://php.net/strtok)

```
$newString=strtok($newString,'&');
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But now I need to also remove everything that is after &. For example http://www.youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI&feature=related should become http://www.youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simpler for you:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aICB2mUu2k';

$url = str_replace('wathc?v=', '/e/', $url);
```

Comment: Use PHP's strpos function.
e.a.

$old = 'youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI&feature=related';

$position = strpos($old, '&');
echo $position; // prints: 25


$new = substr($old, 0, $position);


echo $new; // prints: youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI

Answer (score 0):

See preg_replace in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Regular expressions in this case might be a bit overkill.

Comment: IIRC the PHP manual suggests to use string functions - not regex functions - for the very basic string operations.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment in RiaD's response, I'd suggest this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aICB2mUu2k&feature=related';
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);
$url = 'http://youtube.com/e/' . $query['v'];
```